# Trouble creating a .py file in emacs

Tags: org-mode, init-file, python

Whenever I try to create a python file in Emacs I get this error message:

> unable to find installed server supporting this file. the following
> servers could be installed automatically:

what does this mean and how do I fix it?

Comment: That is not Emacs's default behavior. It must come from something in your configuration or some package that you've installed. Post complete instructions to reproduce the problem with `emacs -Q`.

Answer (score 0):

This message is likely due to [LSP](https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-mode) being installed. You can read more about it [here](https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/). You are using some preconfigured distribution (like e.g. Doom emacs)? Then it is wise to mention and add a tag for it next time. Anyway, I guess the best option is that you just let LSP install the recommended server automatically for now. Or otherwise, if you do not want that, then lookup (or ask in the configuration its help channel) how to disable LSP.

Comment: how do I let it add an automatic server?

Comment: You can choose when that question gets asked, AFAIK